# Is there a way to find what Types are referenced by a c# assembly?

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, system.reflection

The Assembly class has a GetReferencedAssemblies method that returns the
referenced assemblies. Is there a way to find what Types are referenced?

Answer (score 1):

The CLR wont be able to tell you at runtime. You would have to do some serious static analysis of the source files - similar to the static analysis done by resharper or visual studio.

Static analysis is fairly major undertaking. You basically need a c# parser, a symbol table and plenty of time to work through all the cases that come up in abstract syntax trees.

Why can't the CLR tell you at run time? It is just in time compiled, this means that CLR bytcode is converted into machine code just before execution. Reflection only tells you stuff known statically at runtime about your types, and the CLR would only know if a type is referenced when the code is run. The CLR only knows when a type is loaded at execution time - at the point of just in time compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Use [System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Types are not referenced separately from assemblies. If an assembly references another assembly, it automatically references (at least in the technical context) all the types within that assembly, as well. In order to get all the types *defined* (not referenced) in an assembly, you can use the [Assembly.GetTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx) method.

It may be possible, but sounds like a rather arduous task, to scan an assembly for which actual types it references (i.e. which types it actually invokes or otherwise mentions). This will probably involve working with IL. Something like this is best to be avoided.

**Edit:** *Actually, when I think about it, this is not possible at all. Whatsoever. On a quite basic level. The thing is, types can be instantiated and referenced willy-nilly. It's not even uncommon for this to happen. Not to mention late binding. All this means trying to analyze an assembly for all the types it references is something like predicting the future.*

**Edit 2: Comments**

While the question, as stated, isn't possible due to all sorts of dynamic references, it *is* possible greatly shrink all sorts of binary files using *[difference encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding#References)*. This basically allows you to get a file containing the differences between two binary files, which in the case of executables/libraries, tends to be vastly smaller than either of the actual files. Here are some applications that perform this operation. Note that bsdiff doesn't run on Windows, but there is a link to a port there, and you can find many more ports (including to .NET) with the aid of Google.

- [XDelta](http://xdelta.org/)
- [bsdiff](http://www.daemonology.net/bsdiff/)

If you'd look, you'll find many more such applications. One of the best parts is, they are totally self-contained and involve very little work on your part.

Comment: Hi Greg,
Thank you for your fast reply. I need such analysis for incremental build of .csproj files based on changes of source codes. When the assembly "A" changes, in order to know the compilation breaks, I recompile all assemblies references "A". However, In order to shrink the deployment patch, I need to know by changing a type in the assembly "A", which assemblies are not to ship and still working.
Regards,
Shahyad

Comment: You're welcome. Next time though, ask what you really want. Because 'shrinking deployment patch' is a much more reasonable proposition than this one. I'll update my answer accordingly.